Movie about creature who feeds on fear
I came across this movie a few years ago. From what I can remember, it was a sci-fi film.  
The main character and his love interest in the film was being chased by these creatures that would constantly kill him and bring him back to life.   
The creatures fed on the fear of people as they died which was also the only time they allowed people to see them. They are pretty much impossible to kill.   
At the end of the movie you find out the main character is actually one of the creature but because he fell for the girl in the film and could love he became stronger than the rest. 
He was able to kill one of the other creatures which was why they were chasing him to figure out how he got so strong. 

Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

The Deaths of Ian Stone

The story centers on an American man living in Britain, Ian Stone (Vogel), who is killed each day by mysterious beings. He then enters a new existence, unaware of his prior lives. When he begins to remember past existences, he is once again in danger of being killed, with each death more gruesome than the last.




